# What to do with a post that has an incorrect code formatting & it's mostly code

Tags: support, questions, edits, question-quality, editing-help

When I try to edit the format of a post with copy-pasted code and barely any content, I receive an "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details." error. I know it's mostly code and I know it should have more information, but fixing the format should be independent of that. So, what should I do about it?

It happened to me a couple of times already. I tend to fix the format and then comment. But I don't always manage to edit the format, because, well, the post is lacking on content.